# Is there a way to deep link TO adding a widget on the home screen from the app?

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I would love to give the user a way to go to adding a widget in the home screen from the app. So not deep linking **from** the widget **to** the app, but rather *deep linking* **to** widget adding screen **from** the app.

Comment: Did you find a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I don't think there is a way to do it.